# On continuity of complex function

Tags: complex-analysis, continuity

I'd like any hints to study continuity of the function $$f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}, \quad \rho e^{i\theta} \mapsto \rho e^{i\theta\rho}.$$

I think that some problem could appears for points on non-negative real axis.

Also, is there some animation/graph showing this function?

Comment: Note that even the function $$g:\mathbb C\to\mathbb C, \quad \rho e^{i\theta}\mapsto \theta$$ will have problems

Comment: Yes, I think so. The same kind of problem.

Comment: Note that if you select a branch cut along $\theta=\theta_0$, so that we restrict to $\theta\in[\theta_0,\theta_0+2\pi)$, then continuity at a point of the branch cut can occur only when $f(re^{i\theta_0})=f(re^{i(\theta_0+2\pi)})$, i.e., when $r$ is an integer